# How to do custom encoding for md5/sha1 digest in python?

Tags: python, encoding, base64, hashlib

I have written python code where I need file's md5/sha1 digest for further use.

```
import hashlib
md5_file = hashlib.md5(my_file_path).digest()
```

which will generate digest of this sort.

```
'si\x155u\xba\xd2\xf9N^\xabq\xc87\xffh'
```

Now this is hexadecimal representation of md5 in 16 bit.
Next what I did was converted it into list

```
md5hexstring = list(md5_file)
o/p = ['s', 'i', '\x15', '5', 'u', '\xba', '\xd2', '\xf9', 'N', '^', '\xab', 'q', '\xc8', '7', '\xff', 'h']
```

now I want to encode this using custom encoding which has logic like this.

```
pseudo code of logic I want to use:

char_val >> 4 then
if char_val < 6 : new_val = char_val + '3' else : new_val = 'x' + char_val - 7
encoded_val =  encoded_val + new_val
again char_val & 0x0f then
if char_val < 6 : new_val = char_val + '3' else : new_val = 'x' + char_val - 7
encoded_val =  encoded_val + new_val
```

ascii value of character 3 is added eg. '3'=>51 + char_val =

Now this is typically easy in C++ to do but in python I tried `ord()` and `chr()` but this having limit of 255 and checksum calculation will typically have value more than that. So I am not sure how to do this in python.

2 questions here are:

1. Is the way I am converting digest to list for each character processing is correct ? (if not then what is correct way)
2. How do I do the custom encoding according to the pesudocode which I have mentioned above.

PS :

I don't want to use `encode()` api of python for base64 encoding as I need my custom encoding as mentioned above, so please do not suggest that unless I can add my this logic into this api.

Tried referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537750/decode-base64-like-string-with-different-index-tables) but no luck

Comment: one byte can only ever be 0-255 ...

Comment: What would be a proper value > 255 for a byte?

Comment: its not clear at all, are you trying to add the ascii value of `'3' =>51`? or are you trying to add the integer `3`? or are you trying to add the character '3' (ie `'43'`)? ... are you trying to combine the character 'x' with char_val? or sum the ascii value of `'x'`?

Comment: `return ''.join(unichr(ord(c)+3 if ord(c) < 6 else ord(c)+ord('x')-7) for c in digest)`  maybe? ... no idea

Comment: Hi Joran it is using ascii values .. what i did not realize is c++ code takes 1 character and shifts it 4 times char >> 4 and then applies my pseduo code then again char & 0x0f and again same pseduo code is run

Comment: I@JoranBeasley I think your solution might work , if I divide this characters in list properly.
sorry for missing out on ascii value in question ..editing